# What is a $1/2$-net of a sphere and why is this operator norm inequality true?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, normed-spaces, dimension-theory-analysis

I'm reading a paper and I encountered the following:

> Define $T$ to be a $1/2$-net of an $n$ dimensional unit sphere
>   $S^{n-1}$ in the norm $\|\|_2$.

What is the definition of $1/2$ net of a sphere?

I'm not familiar with this terminology and here is my understanding from searching it:
We must have $T \subseteq S$ and $T$ must be $n-1$ dimensional. For any vector $x \in S^{n-1}$, there exists $y \in T$ such that $\|x-y\|_2 \leq 1/2$. Intuitively, $T$ performs a discretization on the sphere. Is my understanding correct?

Given this definition on $T$, they write the following inequalities for the operator norm of matrix $A$:

> $$\|A\|_2 = \sup_{x \in S^{n-1}, y \in \mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}}
> \frac{x^\intercal A y}{\|y\|_2} \leq 2 \sup_{x \in T, y \in
> > \mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}} \frac{x^\intercal A y}{\|y\|_2}$$

Why is the above inequality true?

Comment: It probably means an [$\epsilon$-net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delone_set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $M=\sup_{x \in T, y \in \mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}} \frac{x^\intercal A y}{\|y\|_2}$. Let $x\in S^{n-1}$ and  $y\in\Bbb R^n-\{0\}$. There exists $t\in T$ such that $\|t-x\|_2\le 1/2$. Then

$$\frac {x^{\perp}Ay}{\|y\|_2}= \frac {t^{\perp}Ay}{\|y\|_2}+\frac {(x-t)^{\perp}Ay}{\|y\|_2}\le M+\frac 12\|A\|_2$$

If follows $\|A\|_2\le M+\frac 12\|A\|_2$ and $\|A\|_2\le 2M$.